# Problems adding new AdMob to android app

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, ads

I am trying to add the new AdMob ads to my first application, I managed to arrange the code in the correct way but I have to problems:

First problem is my ad ID **ca-app-pub-61413779example** is getting multiple errors like: **ca** cannot be resolved to a variable, **ba** cannot be resolved to a variable, the literal 
**61413779** of type int is out of range.

The second problem is R.id.**mainLayout**, which is mainLayout, I don't get it.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_screen);


     // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ca-app-pub-61413779example);

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);


        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your admob adding way, but I got another great way to add admob to your app using xml only.

**first** in your manifest add these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

***** the second is most important

**then** add this in your manifest inside the `application` tag

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

now in every activity you want the ad to appear on you add this in the layout.xml of the activity

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

and inside the top parent layout ex. linearlayout you add these *under xmlns:android="xxx*

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

now the ads should work perfectly :D

**UPDATE:** don't forget to download and place the *GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar* under the libs folder.

Comment: please take a look to the screen shot, hope you can help me to get rid of this error.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/21lohlqrsiupmb3/4.jpg

Comment: can you post your activity_basic_screen ?

Comment: very nice and simple, Thanks Ahmed!

Answer (score 1):

The AdView constructor expects a String as the third argument, so you're basically missing double quotes:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-61413779example");
```

As for your XML, ensure that you have the right ID. If only `mainLayout` is underlined, it is not the correct ID. If `R` is underlined, then it means your XML has an error somewhere and R.java isn't being generated.

Comment: please take a look to the screen shot, hope you can help me to get rid of this error. [link](dropbox.com/s/21lohlqrsiupmb3/4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

since you set your content with activity_basic_screen.xml, you have to go to that xml.

you need to show that code for activity_basic_screen.xml and tell where you want to put the ad for specific details

for general, in your activity_basic_screen.xml, you have to have a LinearLayout or other layouts where you want to show/inflate the ad. for the one in your screenshot problem/Linearlayout, you have to have this one:

```
    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
     >
```

you're getting that error because i think you don't have a linear layout with

```
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
```

you can name it differently

```
    android:id="@+id/givenName"
```

but you have to changed your reference in java of findViewById to "R.id.givenName"

for me, i usually use Ahmed's suggestion so i won't need to program it in java but i think programming in java is more dynamic.

hope that helps.

PS. 
in your screenshot you cover your app name/project but you showed your package name. it's like the same thing because you can find your app in google play by using that.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a different answer to what you are looking for, but I would highly recommend using SMART_BANNER Over BANNER. look here at The table that list the standard banner sizes:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Banner: size 320x50 only
Smart Banner: size change to Screen width x 32|50|90

Here is an example on how to do it:

-Layout

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/main_r"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="com.example.adexample">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adView_test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

-Activity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private AdView adView;
      private AdRequest adRequest;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


     MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
     admobCall();

  }

 // Function to Set Ads for Main Layout
 private void admobCall(){

    // Set the RelativeLayout id to the view
    View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adView_test);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    //Real Admob Main Activity Banner
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R"YOUR_ADMOB_AD_ID"));

   // Test google ID for Banner
   // adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

   ((RelativeLayout)adContainer).addView(adView);

   // This Request will bulid the ADs as a Test
   //adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
   //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

  // This Request Will bulid the ADs as Real
  adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

  adView.loadAd(adRequest);

 }
```

Also be sure to add "google()" to the project-level build.gradle, and 
this implementation to dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
```

Check the Implementation instructions site just to be sure you are not missing something:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

**Hope this was helpful :)**